# SDL memory leak with TTF

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl, truetype

I tried to make a basic text drawing class using SDL and TTF
but I got this huge memory leak.. even when I freed the surface :/

this is the textloader.cpp

```
void TextLoader::drawStringWithShadow(string str,SDL_Rect rct,SDL_Color clr,SDL_Surface *screen)
{
    SDL_Color black = {0,0,0};
    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,str.c_str(),black);
    rct.x++;
    rct.y++;
    SDL_BlitSurface(text,NULL,screen,&rct);
    rct.x--;
    rct.y--;
    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,str.c_str(),clr);
    SDL_BlitSurface(text,NULL,screen,&rct);
    SDL_FreeSurface(text);
}
```

and the text loader.h

```
    #pragma once
#include"includes.h"
class TextLoader
{
public:
    TextLoader(const char *Font,int Size);
    ~TextLoader(void);
    void drawString(string str,SDL_Rect rct,SDL_Color clr,SDL_Surface *screen);
    void drawStringWithShadow(string str,SDL_Rect rct,SDL_Color clr,SDL_Surface *screen);
private:
    SDL_Surface *text;
    TTF_Font *font;
};
```

I am calling this from my main loop

Comment: Can you pinpoint the leak using valgrind or similar? It should give you a lot more information than just the fact that you have a leak. Debugging symbols might be needed though.

Comment: I am running Win8. valgrind support linux/unix..
can you recommend me another program?

Comment: Some suggestions can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows).

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `TTF_RenderText_Solid()` twice, yet you free the surface `text` created with it only once. 
On your second call:

```
 text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,str.c_str(),clr);
```

you overwrite the pointer that points to the previous surface creating a memory leak. You do `SDL_FreeSurface()` the second surface but not the first one.

Note: [TTF_RenderText_Solid](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_43.html) returns pointer to completely a new surface.

Comment: I tried to free the surface after the:
SDL_BlitSurface(text,NULL,screen,&rct);

but it is not working wich surface do I need to free?